# How to get EditValue from CheckedComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a `DevExpress CheckedComboBoxEdit` on my form.
In designer i had binded this control with `BindingSource`.

In `BindingSource` i have objects

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Name {set;get;}
}
```

I set `DisplayMember` as `Name` and set `ValueMember` as empty so i expect that i got whole object from `EditValue`.

Now i want to bind this control with my view model

```
public class MyViewModel{
  ***
  public List<MyClass> TestList{set;get;}
  ***

  public MyViewModel(){
     TestList = new List<MyClass>();
  }
}
```

After i run app with this form. Select values in control.
 But after i see that `MyViewModel.TestList` is empty.
And CheckedComboBoxEdit.EditValue contains list of `MyClass.Name` what is i setted as `DisplayMember`.

It is possible to bind `CheckedComboBoxEdit` to property and make taht EditValue retunr whole object?

Comment: Can you add the code where you bind your VM to the `CheckedComboBoxEdit`

Comment: @Fourat i did all bindings in designer.

Comment: check the code behind it has to be there